# How decode xfs lost+found directory

Tags: software-raid, xfs, inode

I have managed to trash my homebrew Nas box (an old hp d530 + 2x 750gb sata soft raid1 + 17gb boot disk with ubuntu server 8.10)

I have searched the web and tried to repair the file system but to no avail :( I was thinking that the dirs/files located under the root of the lost+found directory are 64 bit numbers.
Is there any way that I could decant the number into binary form, from there reconstruct the directory/file structure.

More to the point can anyone point to the information on how xfs inodes are broken down(does that make sense)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The files names in lost+found are just the inode of the file.  There's no way to map this back to a filename; they're in lost+found because the directory entry for these files couldn't be located.  An inode is just a number and doesn't have any intrinsic meaning.

However, if your files contain Extended Attributes, and these Extended Attributes could point to original path, then you can reconstruct the directory/file structure by decoding Extended Attributes.

Comment: Thanks for that.

Hey ho, sort through the directories manually... for me :(